# Bind two Services on Bluemix

Tags: web-services, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I would like to publish an API as a Service. This API however requires Object Storage Service.

Is it possible to bind a Service with another Service? What would be the best approach to publish such an API which needs to be bound to a Service? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a service as a Cloud Foundry application (or choosing another compute option like containers if applicable) with the Object Storage service bound to that application.

In your application, you can expose a consumable API which performs your business logic.